# Pascals find the sum

Tags: c#-4.0

According to above rules what is the maximum sum of below input? It means please take this pyramid as an input (as file or constants directly inside the code) for your implementation and solve by using it.

```
215
193 124
117 237 442
218 935 347 235
320 804 522 417 345
229 601 723 835 133 124
248 202 277 433 207 263 257
359 464 504 528 516 716 871 182
461 441 426 656 863 560 380 171 923
381 348 573 533 447 632 387 176 975 449
223 711 445 645 245 543 931 532 937 541 444
330 131 333 928 377 733 017 778 839 168 197 197
131 171 522 137 217 224 291 413 528 520 227 229 928
223 626 034 683 839 053 627 310 713 999 629 817 410 121
924 622 911 233 325 139 721 218 253 223 107 233 230 124 233
```

Note that, each node has only two children here (except the most bottom ones). As an example, you can walk from 215 to 124 (because 193 is a prime) then from 124 to either 237 or 442. From 124 you cannot go to 117 because it’s not a direct child of 124.

Comment: Edited to format the numbers actually as a pyramid

Comment: please send me the answer Some one